# JavaFX: Cross-Platform Button Resizing Issue

Tags: user-interface, button, javafx, cross-platform

I'm having a bit of trouble using JavaFX, particularly when it comes to changing platforms.  The text shown on buttons will appear just fine on my Windows computer, but on my Macbook the text gets cut off. [See pictures]   This is extremely bothersome when working as a group and constantly running a program on different computers.  Both pictures are showing the exact same program. Here's a link to the program repo. if you're interested in seeing the code: https://github.com/Evilscaught/ResizableProgram

[Program as seen on Windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBSX4.png) [image]

[Program as seen on OS X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hTkw.png) [image]